# Mojolicious Deploying database schema

Tags: perl, dbix-class, mojolicious

I am currently working through [this tutorial](http://oliverguenther.de/2014/04/applications-with-mojolicious-part-four-database-schemas-with-dbixclass/) on building a Mojolicious web app for a project. In the tutorial he talks about using this in a script to create a database schema.

```
my $schema = Moblo::Schema->connect('dbi:SQLite:moblo.db');
$schema->deploy();
```

and I have tried running `perl -e '...'`, putting it in different files and everything else I can think of, but with no success.

[Here is my code](https://github.com/caseycole589/MojoDojo) on GitHub.

I am pretty lost on how to get this thing to create the schema so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please learn to use *markdown* to mark up your posts. There is a question mark in an orange circle at the top right of your edit box that links to *Markdown Editing Help*

Comment: I didn't know sorry about that tried to fix up some of it and will make sure to do it in the future.

Comment: That's okay—I realised you weren't familiar with markdown and did it for you in my edit from version 1 to 2. Your own changes in the latest version were unnecessary and nothing to do with markdown so I rolled them back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why the author wrote only a part of the deployment script. Perhaps he thought it was obvious that you needed `use Moblo::Schema` in there. Perhaps he was right.

This program works fine. Call it anything you like—say `deploy.pl`—and put it in the `moblo/lib` directory.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Moblo::Schema;

my $schema = Moblo::Schema->connect('dbi:SQLite:moblo.db');
$schema->deploy();
```

Comment: Author here, this is exactly what I meant - A snippet of code to embed *somewhere* to an init script of your application, and obviously, one has to load the schema module. I've cleared that up in the blog entry with a full example.