# Perl Mojolicious Model

Tags: perl, model-view-controller, mojolicious

I am creating a
[*Mojolicious*](https://mojolicious.org)
application but I can't understand the [documentation for creating a model](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Growing#Model).

Could someone provide an example of how to create a model, run a raw SQL query and get the results in a controller to pass to the view?

I am thinking of something like this:

#### Model

```
package LS::Model::Dt;  
use Mojo::Base;  
use DBI;  

# Here is what I don't understand
# Do I need to create a subroutine that connects to the database like this?  

sub connect_db {

  my $user       = 'user_sql';
  my $pass       = 'pass_sql';
  my $connection = "dbi:Sybase:server=db.sql-srv.com;database=Adventure";
  my $dbh = DBI->connect($connection, $user, $pass) or die 'Cannot connect';
}  

sub queries{

  my $query_selectall = "select * from foo";
  my $all_query       = $dbh->selectall_arrayref($query_selectall, {Slice => {}});
}
```

#### Controller

```
package LS::Controller::Home;

use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Controller';
use LS::Model::Dt

sub home {
    my $self = shift;

    # Somehow get the query results here
    my $query_res = #somehow get the query results here

    $self->render(res=>$query_res);
}


1;
```

Comment: Have you considered using [`Mojolicious::Lite`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Lite)? It does all that you should need if you're just beginning.

Comment: Fun. After a quick search I can find approximately zero documentation on models in Mojolicious. Even your link just shows what's essentially a random class with a singleton instance.

Comment: @Borodin  Yes, but I need to learn to this the MVC way, thanks for the fast reply

Comment: @melpomene yes, unfortunately the documentation especially with examples is rare, thanks for the reply

Comment: @rooger: I suggest that you start with `Mojolicious::Lite` and work from there, learning the infrastructure as you encounter it. The official IRC channel `#mojo` on `irc.perl.org` is excellent for support.

Comment: Consider looking at DBIx::Class and specifically Schema::Loader. If you have a database set up already, you can autodiscover this, to obtain a $schema object, which you could use as your model of the database.

Comment: @bytepusher  hello, right now I am reading about this, is it possible to provide a short example of a connection/query/ sending data to controller/view?

Comment: @melpomene you can't find docs on models because Mojo intentionally doesn't tie itself to a specific model structure. I'm sure if you'd look for the docs for Catalyst, which does include the model layer, you'll find examples.

Comment: @AGoldMan Then maybe the documentation should say that, and not ["*A slightly modified version of \[Model View Controller\] moving some application logic into the controller is the foundation of pretty much every web framework these days, including Mojolicious.*"](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Growing#Model-View-Controller)

Answer (score 2):

Later edit:  I have managed somehow via this tutorial:
http://oliverguenther.de/2014/04/applications-with-mojolicious-part-four-database-schemas-with-dbixclass/
Github code for when you are now sure where the author is creating a file is available here:
https://github.com/oliverguenther/Moblo
If you encounter problems also check this:
[Mojolicious Deploying database schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29091017/mojolicious-deploying-database-schema)